# non-video blender resources?

Tags: modeling

I am looking for blender tutorials, but most of the ones I've seen are videos. it's very hard to use a video because even the good ones are hard to follow, as some actions the speaker mumbles through, or does some fancy key combination that doesn't show up on screen nor is explained. is there any site that has text-and-picture tutorials?

Comment: [Blenderguru](http://www.blenderguru.com) usually has text versions under the videos.

Comment: For a general guide you might find http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Blender_3D:_Noob_to_Pro useful.

Comment: We also maintain a list of resources here: http://meta.blender.stackexchange.com/questions/40/beginners-reference

Comment: Our Python tutorials have detailed written descriptions and some of the tutorials are in Text form: www.blenderdiplom.com
Hope that helps.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about blender as defined in the [help center](http://blender.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)